# How do I use a variable in the "style" tag?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I use a variable in this line? My variables are "rand1" and "rand2"

```
style="position:absolute; TOP:'rand1'px; LEFT:'rand2'px"
```

This is my full code.

```
<script>
var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1  
var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1
</script>

<img id="myImage" 
src="redsquare.jpg" 
width="100" 
height="100" 
style="position:absolute; TOP:'rand1'px; LEFT:'rand2'px"
onClick="alert(rand1); alert(rand2)">
```

My intention for this code is for an image to pop up on screen at a random location, and it is clickable, but this code only puts the red square image at the top left corner.

In position:absolute, there would usually be a number where my variables are, and there would be no quotation marks, so it would look like this:

```
style="position:absolute; TOP:100px; LEFT:200px"
```

I thought I could just replace the numbers with a variable, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script variables are not evaluated when parsing css values.

You can use script to change the style value

```
<img id="myImage" src="redsquare.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="position:absolute;" onClick="alert(rand1); alert(rand2)" />
<script>
    myImage.style.top = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000) + 'px';
    myImage.style.top = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000) + 'px';
</script>
```

Note that the script is placed after the element is created.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead do a `document.write()` in JavaScript for the `<img>`:

```
<script>
var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1  
var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1
document.write("<img ... style='position:absolute; TOP:"+rand1+"px"+" LEFT:"+rand2+"px' ...");
</script>
```

Or simply change the values of `.top` and `.left` via JavaScript. For example:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").style.top = rand1;
document.getElementById("myImage").style.left = rand2;
```